# Determine sin, cos, and tan

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Determine sin, cos and tan for:

$\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{3}$

$-\frac{\pi}{6},-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{3}$

$\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3 \pi}{4}, \frac{5 \pi}{4}, \frac{7 \pi}{4}, \frac{9 \pi }{4}$

$-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac{3 \pi}{4},-\frac{5 \pi}{4},-\frac{7 \pi}{4},-\frac{9 \pi}{4}$

$\frac{5 \pi}{6}, \frac{7 \pi}{6}, \frac{2 \pi}{3},-\frac{2 \pi}{3}, \frac{4 \pi}{3}$

My teacher wants me to draw a unit circle and a triangle for each question, won't it be many for this? 21 unit circles and triangles? I was told somewhere that I only need to use the $30$-$60$-$90$ triangle to get the other trig values. Can someone help me?

Here is the picture showing us how to determine the values:

[image: diagrams]

In the bottom he says ”do similar drawings for other angles in the assignment”, in the pic we've $-π/4$, $π/4$, $3π/4$, and $-3π/4$.  But technically they're not the same, $π/4$ is $45$ degrees, $-π/4$ is $315$ degrees.

Comment: I suggest finding the coordinates where the terminal sides of the angles $\pi/6$, $\pi/4$, and  $\pi/3$ intersect the unit circle, then using symmetry to find the coordinates of the remaining angles.

Comment: If you have worked out the values for $\pi/6$ and $\pi/3$, you should include that in your post.

Comment: Technically $-\pi/4$ is $-45$ degrees, but it results in the same point on the unit circle as $315$ degrees and therefore has the same sine and cosine.

Comment: In the lower right part of the picture you can see how one triangle solves two of the angles you were given: $5\pi/4$ and $-3\pi/4.$ So that is two angles already solved for you. Several of your angles come in pairs like this that can be solved by a single triangle. But I think the point of the exercise **is** to draw a lot of triangles, at least one for each point on the unit circle that the angles go to. Later you will see how symmetries of the diagrams allow you to deduce all these trig functions just by knowing the functions of $\pi/6$ and $\pi/4.$

Answer (score -1):

First of all buy a compass, they are sold at Daiso or Seria or Poundland or Kronaland, or whatever you have in Sweden, for one euro.

Second it will help you if you have a diagram of the values of cosine and sine and tangent between $-2\pi$ and $2\pi$.

Wolfram Alpha doesn't seem to understand my range of values: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sine%2C+cosine%2C+tangent+from+%5B-2pi%2C+2pi%5D

Third, these identities will help you:
$$
\sin (-x)=-\sin x
$$
$$
\sin (\pi-x)=\sin x
$$
$$
\cos (-x)=\cos x
$$
$$
\cos (\pi-x)=-\cos x
$$
$$
\tan (-x)=-\tan x
$$

Fourth, your teacher asked you to do $\pi/4$ twice, and $9\pi/4$ is the same as $\pi/4$.